# Only allow Google to view sitemap.xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to limit access to `sitemap.xml` only if it's accessed by Google with the following code:

```
reverse_dns = Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)
throw_404 unless reverse_dns.include?("goog") || reverse_dns.include?("localhost")
```

But it fails if there is no hostname for the ip address. For example:

`Resolv::ResolvError: no name for 64.233.191.255`

Which is a google bot ip address.

Any idea on how to accomplish this or how Stackoverflow does this (Stackexchange limits it's sitemap.xml to Google also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using reverse DNS, use whois -- since some of Google's ip's don't even have the reverse dns records setup.

So do a full whois on the ip instead using the `whois` gem:

`gem "whois"`

```
whois = Whois.whois(request.remote_ip).parts[0]['body']
throw_404 unless whois.include?("google") || whois.include?("IANA Special Use")
```

The `IANA Special Use` is usually when you're querying a local network ip address (127.0.0.1 or 10.0.1.1, etc).